# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row on CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_ratings_businesses1

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I'm getting this error when i try to insert new ratings

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yuldi`.`users_ratings`, CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_ratings_businesses1` FOREIGN KEY (`business_id`) REFERENCES `businesses` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

below database table structure with some foreign keys. i'm confused with adding multiple primary and foreign keys. please help me to sort out this issue

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yuldi`.`businesses` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `slug` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `suburb` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `business_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `business_address` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `business_postal` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `business_postal_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `business_phone` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `business_phone1` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `business_phone2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `business_email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `business_website` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `business_details` VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,
  `business_openinghours` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `business_service` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `business_addtionalinfo` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `business_lat` FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `business_lng` FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `identity` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 232
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yuldi`.`ratings` (
  `id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `model` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` FLOAT(8,4) NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `comment` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQUE_RATING` (`model` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yuldi`.`users` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_password` CHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_code` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_status` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 14
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yuldi`.`users_ratings` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating_id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `business_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `rating_id`, `business_id`),
  INDEX `fk_users_has_ratings_ratings1_idx` (`rating_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_has_ratings_users1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_has_ratings_businesses1_idx` (`business_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_ratings_businesses1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`business_id`)
    REFERENCES `yuldi`.`businesses` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_ratings_ratings1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`rating_id`)
    REFERENCES `yuldi`.`ratings` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_ratings_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `yuldi`.`users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from this:

```
 CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_ratings_businesses1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`business_id`)
  REFERENCES `yuldi`.`businesses` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

The record you're trying to insert / update - probably `user_ratings` - is foreign keyed to the `businesses` table; you can't create a user_ratings record without a business_id, and that business_id must actually exist as an `id` in the businesses table.

Comment: INSERT INTO `yuldi`.`users_ratings` (`user_id`, `rating_id`, `business_id`) VALUES ('2', '0320c1cd-c861-11e3-8b52-14feb5b6bcc4', '3'); business_id 3 exists in businesses table with column id

Comment: @SurjitSidhu: Check in table `businesses` if `id` has a value `3`. This is what your input is for `business_id` in `users_ratings` table.

Comment: Yes row with id 3 exists in businesses table

Comment: If that's your `INSERT` statement, that's the problem - it's not valid for the `businesses` table, and if a row with that id already exists, try an `UPDATE` statement instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: now i"m getting this error 
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yuldi`.`users_ratings`, CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_ratings_ratings1` FOREIGN KEY (`rating_id`) REFERENCES `ratings` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)